# Why do geom_density and stat_density(geom = "line") give different results?

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the following illustration, why do `geom_density` and `stat_density(geom = "line")` give different results?

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  x.values = c(
    rnorm(100, mean = 1, sd = 1),
    rnorm(100, mean = 4, sd = 1),
    rnorm(100, mean = 7, sd = 1),
    rnorm(100, mean = 10, sd = 1)
  ),
  mean.values = sort(rep(c(1, 4, 7, 10), 100))
)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x.values, color = mean.values, group = mean.values))

p + geom_density()
```

[image: geom_density results]

```
p + stat_density(geom = "line")
```

[image: stat_density results]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a difference in the `position` argument. The default in `stat_density` is `position = "stack"`, whilst with `geom_density()` it is `position = "identity"`.

If you call `p + stat_density(geom = "line", position = "identity")` you get the same as `geom_density()`:

[image]

Comment: Interesting, thanks.  I tried quickly changing this to `p + stat_density(geom = "area", fill = NA)`, but that still doesn't give the same result as `p + geom_density()`.

Comment: @JakeFisher Sorry - I was distracted and didn't notice the "cumulative" density line, only the area/line differences. This seems to be due to differences in the `position` argument for the stat and the geom.

Comment: @GavinSimpson Could you please tell what does identity mean in position?

Comment: @NaveenGabriel It means the identity function, a function that returns it's input unchanged. I'm not sure if this is a common usage outside stats, but it crops up as a link function in GLMs, which means that a GLM with a Gaussian distribution and identity link function includes linear regression (OLS) as a special case. In the case of **ggplot2** it simply means don't adjust position; other `position` types do adjust the position.